# A gardener having $120 \ \mathrm m$ of fencing wishes to enclose a rectangular

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, area

> A gardener having $120 \ \mathrm m$ of fencing wishes to enclose a rectangular plot of land and also erect a fence across the land parallel to two of the sides. Find the maximum area he can enclose.

**My attempt:**

Let $x$ and $y$ be the length and breadth of rectangle. Then
$$2(x+y)=120\implies x+y=60 \implies y=60-x$$

Now, $$A=xy\implies A=x(60-x)\implies A=60x-x^2$$
Then, $A'=60-2x$

$A'=0$ gives 
$x=30$ and $y=30$. 
Is it correct?

Comment: This is very clearly the kind of routine question that comes from homework or an exam. Where did you encounter the problem - what level of course?  This kind of context is an important part of a good post.

Answer (score 5):

Not correct. You forgot to take into account the extra fence that goes across the land.

So, you need to start with $2x +3y=120$

Comment: could you elaborate how $3y$??

Comment: @blue_eyed_... Just draw a picture: Say $x$ is the length of the side of the rectangle, and $y$ the length of top and bottom. Then you need one more fence going from left to right crossing the land, parallel to both top and bottom. So you need another fence of length $y$ (of course, you can also place the extra fence top to bottom, and now you get $3x+2y=120$, but by symmetry the math will work out the same).

Comment: and what about the area?

Comment: That's still $x \cdot y$

Answer (score 0):

No, your answer is not correct.

Your $$2(x+y)=120$$ should have been $$3y+2x=120$$

You forgot about the middle fence.

My final answer is $x=30$ and $y=20$ with the maximum area of  $600$